# Rails has many :through relationship causing stack level too deep

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :case_users
  has_many :cases, :through => :case_users
end

class CaseUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :case
  belongs_to :user
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :case_users
  has_many :users, :through => :case_users
end
```

When I try to hit any users or cases endpoint, it continually sends queries to the DB like:

```
SELECT `cases`.* FROM `cases` INNER JOIN `case_users` ON `cases`.`id` = `case_users`.`case_id` WHERE `cases`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `case_users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `case_users`.`user_id` = 1  [["user_id", 1]]
```

and like:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `case_users` ON `users`.`id` = `case_users`.`user_id` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `case_users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `case_users`.`case_id` = 1  [["case_id", 1]]
```

Why is this happening?

Edit:

These models are actually much larger (80-100 lines), but I've commented bits out and believe this is what's causing the problem/error.  Also it's running these queries when crashing, which leads me to believe that it's coming from this relationship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73181/discussion-between-broisatse-and-noah-matisoff).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73193/discussion-on-question-by-noah-matisoff-rails-has-many-through-relationship-cau).

Answer (score 0):

After spending ~1 hour looking at my models, my database schema, and testing all over, I found it was a problem in my serializer.

I had `has_many :users` in my serializer for cases, and that caused the error.